# GAP computational group action question

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, gap

Let $G$ be a group generated by some permutations $G = \langle A,B,C,D,E \rangle$. Suppose $G$ acts on a set $X$.

Given some subset $X' \subseteq X$ and an injective map $f : X' \to X$, How can I search for short words of the group whose action on $X$ agrees with $f$?

Basically I want to find short words like $ABC'ACD$ that permute a couple things to given locations, but I don't mind what it does to anything else.

So far I've looked at `EpimorphismFromFreeGroup(G:names:=["A","B","C","D","E"]);` and converted the generators of various stabilizers to words.

Comment: Are you trying to find all words up to a given length with the specified property - or would it be enough if you found a shortest such word?

Comment: @DerekHolt I just want to find one (or more) reasonably short words that satisfy the criteria. It doesn't have to be shortest and I don't need all of them. I am able to find valid words with `RepresentativeAction` but they are longer than necessary.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could describe a typical example that you would like to be able to compute, just to get an idea of how large $|G|$ and $|X|$ are likely to be.

Comment: I'm working on the 2x2x2 (and hopefully later the 3x3x3) rubiks cubes, so the group has order 3 million and acts on 24 points (the stickers). At the moment I want to find permutations that do specific things to white stickers on the top layer and leave the bottom layer alone - they are free to do anything with the other top layer stickers and hopefully this would let me find small words.

Comment: You might want to look at page 98ff in https://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf

Comment: The group of the $2\times 2\times 2$ is small enough for it to be feasible to compute the shortest word exactly. You are looking for a shortest word in a coset, and there are a number of ways of doing that - you could for example compute a presentation of the group and then calculate the coset table of the subgroup. The $3 \times 3 \times 3$ group is very much larger, and would require different techniques. There are good heuristic methods for finding reasonably short words for group elements, and I would expect the same to be true for coseyt representatives.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank's so much for this information! What subgroup would be involved in the coset computation you mention?

Comment: The subgroup would be the pointwise stabilizer of $f(X')$.